# PHP, TimThumb filters not working online

Tags: php, image, filter, gd

A little help from those who’ve used Timthumb before.

http://themes.amplus.gambit.ph/wp-content/themes/amplus/functions/timthumb.php?src=http://themes.amplus.gambit.ph/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/12979795614923485443_a1967ff888_b.jpg&w=860&h=300&f=5,255,0,0,0

This image should be tinted red because of the GET parameter f=5,255,0,0,0. This is tinted red when I do it locally, but it no filters are applied when it’s online.

There’re no PHP errors showing up, and the uploaded code is already tested locally without a hitch. The permissions of the folders are correct, the file is locally available, the PHP version is high enough 5.2.10, GD is supported, in short, everything looks okay.

Anyone got a clue why this is happening? I couldn’t find anything online about this.

Comment: did you find the correct answer? i'm having the same problem works locally but not remotely, my timthumb suffixed like so - '&amp;h=260&amp;w=348&amp;zc=1&amp;f=2|3,-40|5,72,60,44,1'

Comment: Hey @Cam, check out my own answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timthumb filters require PHP's bundled GD library to be used since this version include some necessary GD functions which are not included in the non-bundled ones. More specifically, **PHP with a bundled GD library should show these statements as TRUE**:

```
function_exists('imagefilter')
function_exists('imagerotate')
function_exists('imagecreatetruecolor')
function_exists('imageconvolution')
```